# Pandas - Matching reference number to find earliest date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping to pick your brains on optimization.  I am still learning more and more about python and using it for my day to day operation analyst position.  One of the tasks I have is sorting through approx 60k unique record identifiers, and searching through another dataframe that has approx 120k records of interactions, the employee who authored the interaction and the time it happened.

For Reference, the two dataframes at this point look like:

main_data = Unique Identifier Only
nok_data = Authored By Name, Unique Identifer(known as Case File Identifier), Note Text, Created On.

My set up currently runs it at approximately sorting through and matching my data at 2500 rows per minute, so approximately 25-30 minutes or so for a run.  What I am curious is are there any steps I performed that are:

1. Redundant and inefficient overall slowing my process
2. A poor use of syntax to work around my lack of knowledge.

Below is my code:

```
nok_data = pd.read_csv("raw nok data.csv") #Data set from warehouse

main_data = pd.read_csv("exampledata.csv") #Data set taken from iTx ids from referral view

row_count = 0
error_count = 0
print(nok_data.columns.values.tolist())
print(main_data.columns.values.tolist()) #Commented out, used to grab header titles if needed.
data_length = len(main_data) #used for counting how many records left.
earliest_nok = {}
nok_data["Created On"] = pd.to_datetime(nok_data["Created On"]) #convert all dates to datetime at beginning.


for row in main_data["iTx Case ID"]:
    list_data = []
    nok = nok_data["Case File Identifier"] == row 
    matching_dates = nok_data[["Created On", "Authored By Name"]][nok == True]    #takes created on date only if nok shows row was true
    if len(matching_dates) > 0:
        try:
            min_dates = matching_dates.min(axis=0)
            earliest_nok[row] = [min_dates[0], min_dates[1]]
        except ValueError:
            error_count += 1
            earliest_nok[row] = None

    row_count += 1
    print("{} out of {} records").format(row_count, data_length)


with open('finaloutput.csv','wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in earliest_nok.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Looking for any advice or expertise from those performing code like this much longer then I have.  I appreciate all of you who even just took the time to read this.  Happy Tuesday,

Andy M.

**** EDIT REQUESTED TO SHOW DATA
Sorry for my novice move there not including any data type.

main_data example

```
ITX Case ID
2017-023597
2017-023594
2017-023592
2017-023590
```

nok_data aka "raw nok data.csv"

```
Authored By:   Case File Identifier:   Note Text:    Authored on
John Doe         2017-023594           Random Text     4/1/2017 13:24:35
John Doe         2017-023594           Random Text     4/1/2017 13:11:20
Jane Doe         2017-023590           Random Text     4/3/2017 09:32:00
Jane Doe         2017-023590           Random Text     4/3/2017 07:43:23
Jane Doe         2017-023590           Random Text     4/3/2017 7:41:00
John Doe         2017-023592           Random Text     4/5/2017 23:32:35
John Doe         2017-023592           Random Text     4/6/2017 00:00:35
```

Comment: You should post some sample data [MCVE].  First glance is that iterating by row is very slow.

Comment: Can you provide some dummy data for `main_data` and `nok_data`?

Comment: Hello @Alexander I added a few rows of basic data for each.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @Vaishali The expected output it as the end of the code.  It takes the dictionary of earliest_nok and the key has two values of [Created On, Authored By] being written to a csv to be then used in Tableau to match up with other KPI.

Comment: @A.McMaster Given the sample data, can you please show what that dictionary should look like?

Comment: @Alexander currently how my dictionary would be formatted as: earliest_nok = {2017-023594: [Datetime(2017-4-1 13:11:20), "John Doe"]} and so forth for each record.

Comment: Is the author always unique to the Case File?

Comment: @Alexander in terms of its uniqueness on the nok_data set, not always per identifier.  For context, imagine a call center where depending on case load, an additional rep may help another rep with their case and author a contact note.  But, in terms of what I am attempting to mine, there will always be only one rep per case file identifier for earliest contact record.  I hope that was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to group on the `Case File Identifier` and get the minimum date and corresponding author.

```
# Sort the data by `Case File Identifier:` and `Authored on` date 
# so that you can easily get the author corresponding to the min date using `first`.

nok_data.sort_values(['Case File Identifier:', 'Authored on'], inplace=True)
df = (
    nok_data[nok_data['Case File Identifier:'].isin(main_data['ITX Case ID'])]
    .groupby('Case File Identifier:')['Authored on', 'Authored By:'].first()
)
d = {k: [v['Authored on'], v['Authored By:']] for k, v in df.to_dict('index').iteritems()}

>>> d
{'2017-023590': ['4/3/17 7:41', 'Jane Doe'],
 '2017-023592': ['4/5/17 23:32', 'John Doe'],
 '2017-023594': ['4/1/17 13:11', 'John Doe']}

>>> df
                        Authored on Authored By:
Case File Identifier:                           
2017-023590             4/3/17 7:41     Jane Doe
2017-023592            4/5/17 23:32     John Doe
2017-023594            4/1/17 13:11     John Doe
```

It is probably easier to use `df.to_csv(...)`.

The items from main_data['ITX Case ID'] where there is no matching record have been ignored but could be included if required.

Comment: this will be my rookiness in coding with it all compact but I attempted to work my way through and figure it out.  When outputting to a csv it combines both into one line with no space.  Would I create a new column in the dataframe to hold onto the information separately? as well as grabbing the authored by from that particular time stamp?  Thank you!

Comment: I've edited it.  Is this in line with what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have marked the answer as correct and you were 100% right that writing the dataframe to csv was the more efficient clean way to work with the data. I am still learning pandas so your solution of matching is a bit over my head, but hoping to work my way through the documentation when I get the chance.  For reference, the code went from a 25+ min to less then 3 minutes even with the pd.to_datetime.  Thank you so much for your expertise, Andy.

Comment: In your previous code, I believe the `min` function was returning the sorted name of the person not necessarily corresponding to the min date.  In general, you almost always want to avoid looping rows in a dataframe. Glad to have helped.